# google translate selectbox

Tags: google-translate

I came across this site: http://www.iobit.com/ and I found a selectbox on the top right of the page that translates the page using google translate.

Would somebody explain me how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Original Source](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) for Google Translate Tool.

Comment: An answer should summarize the solution, instead of just linking to a resource. Answers, as well as questions, should remain useful even if links in them stopped working (as links often do).